# how to pass param to service in serverless.yaml

Tags: python, aws-lambda, serverless

I'm try to set environment in serverless.yaml

```
service: ${param:env, 'dev'}-backend-offline-onboard
frameworkVersion: '2 || 3'
```

I'm using command

```
sls deploy --param="env=dev" -c serverless.yml
```

but error

```
Cannot resolve serverless.yml: "service" property is not accessible (configured behind variables which cannot be resolved at this stage)
```

how to pass param to service in serverless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any custom param in serverless.
In the command you just have to pass it as

```
serverless deploy --customParam testTest
```

in the serverless.yml file you can use your passed params anywhere as `${opt:customParam}`

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I'm using ${opt:stage} and it's work for me.
<3

Comment: This is no longer the case since version `3.3`:
https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/deprecations#handling-of-unrecognized-cli-options

Answer (score 0):

you can Specify the version by pass

```
--stage=dev
```

and set

```
service: backend-offline-onboard
```

no need to add extra parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm using ${opt:stage} and it's work for me. <3